# Smoke Domain Recolors Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I am using Blender v2.79 Cycles and have tried computing with both GPU and CPU, the results are the same.

(Edit): So there is the domain of the fire + smoke is overlaying a blue tint(the color of my fire) in the volume it takes up, but my material nodes seem to be "Correct". Also, I know it has to be the smoke domain since the rectangle disappears when I disable it while rendering.

The rendered picture(partially rendered)
[image: The rendered picture]

Here are the Material Nodes

[image]

In case it would be helpful: here is the border of the domain
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what we are looking at here. What is your question? Could you explain the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...I solved it...
There wasn't anything wrong with the smoke, but the light was going through a transparent shader mixed with a diffuse shader which was blue, projecting the blue tint on the surface of the Earth